# Pass xml to oracle procedure in java (ojdbc)

Tags: java, xml, oracle, stored-procedures

How do i pass xml document from java to `CallableStatement`

Code where i prepare XML document:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory =
DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = 
dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.newDocument();

// root element
org.w3c.dom.Element rootElement = doc.createElement("data");
doc.appendChild(rootElement);

org.w3c.dom.Element object_id = doc.createElement("object_id");
rootElement.appendChild(object_id);
object_id.appendChild(createElement(doc, "attribuName1", "value1"));
object_id.appendChild(createElement(doc, "attribuName2", "value2"));
```

XML structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<data>
    <object_id>
        <field name="name2" value="2"/>
        <field name="name1" value="1"/>
    </object_id>
</data>
```

now i create `CallableStatement` to call procedure and pass some values as well i want to pass here xml doc.

```
CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall("{? = CALL SCHEMA.PROC_DATA_XML(?,?,?)}");
cstmt.setString(1, "StringParam1");
cstmt.setInt(2, 9999);
//!this is where i want to pass that XML document. So how should i do this? I tried this one:
cstmt.setObject(3, doc);

cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
cstmt.executeUpdate();
float result = cstmt.getInt(1);
```

procedure code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC_DATA_XML(
    ID  IN SCHEMA.XML.ID%TYPE ,--varchar(4)
    ID2  IN SCHEMA.XML.ID2%TYPE ,--number(4)
    RESULT  OUT SCHEMA.XML.RESULT%TYPE, -- 0 – OK 1 – NOT OK
    XML_DATA IN SCHEMA.XML.DATA_CONTENT%TYPE --XML File
    ) IS
BEGIN
```

Maybe someone can provide me with another way of how to do this in java?

Comment: Please , show in the question `SCHEMA.XML` structure.

Comment: @Seyran i added it

Comment: If I there you, I'll pass last param as CLOB.

Comment: I didn't clearly understand what is the `SCHEMA.XML` ?

Answer (score 0):

https://blog.padmarag.com/2011/03/11/call-oracle-plsql-procedure-with-xmltype-from-java-using-jdbc/

Information and example from this site solved my problem.